# Error with struct2table command

Tags: matlab

I am getting the following error while running a program.

```
??? Undefined function or method 'struct2table' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
Error in ==> cellarray at 13  
T=struct2table(parameter,'AsArray',true);
```

The program is as under

```matlab
a=10;
b=15;
parameter(a).alpha_star=0;
parameter(b).gamma_star=0;
x=5;
for j=1:b
    for i=1:a
    parameter(i).alpha_star=x+i;

    end
parameter(j).gamma_star = x^2+j;    
end  
T=struct2table(parameter,'AsArray',true);
```

Can you please tell me, where am I wrong?

Comment: Type `which struct2table`. I'm guessing you get `'struct2table' not found.`, meaning you have a version of MATLAB pre-R2013b.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have a matlab older than R2013b, and since do not have this function (you can check that via `which struct2table`).
you can try to work around it by using `struct2array` and `reshape`.

you can also use

```
alp=[]; 
gam =[];
for i=1:length(parameter)
    if ~isempty(parameter(i).alpha_star)
        alp(end+1)=(parameter(i).alpha_star);
    end
    if ~isempty(parameter(i).gamma_star)
        gam(end+1)=(parameter(i).gamma_star);
    end
end
```

to extract the values to seperate arrays and

```
fieldnames(parameter);
```

to get the fieldnames, this is dirty but if it is only needed for presentation...

Comment: Yes, I have Matlab R2013a, and this function does't work in it. Actually, I want to show my results with the field name. And further, there are two arrays of unequal size, I want to show both of them in one table. Is there any other way to handle it while I keep using structures.

Comment: could you give me an example how the output should look in the above example?

Comment: alpha_star   gamma_Star

Comment: Its difficult for me to write the in proper form. I basically want to get the output in the two columns with heading as alpha_star ...gamma_star. and the resulting values below these headings as a columns.